# Does the ensemble of effective Lagrangians in the String theory landscape mostly include gauge theories?

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, 1pi-effective-action, string-theory-landscape

String theory false vacua can be described by effective Lagrangians at low energy. Is there generally a correspondence between these effective Lagrangians and SU(N) gauge theories? Or do the effective Lagrangians often not respect local invariance with respect to some or any gauge groups?

Comment: In $d=4$, there must be pretty much always a gauge group in the spectrum. It's not a theorem but there's strong evidence for it. Note that to find a gauge group, it's enough to find any spin-one light string excitation. A Yang-Mills symmetry must exist to render its negative-norm time-like polarization harmless - in fact, one may explicitly show by stringy methods that the gauge symmetry is there in any formalism that is Lorentz-covariant. The spin-1 fields arise either from the 10D gauge group e.g. in braneworlds or heterotic strings or from the RR fields or B-fields wrapped on cycles.

Comment: @Luboš Motl -- Great, thanks! Do you know of any references (or key words to search for) that I could look up?